# Safari App Extension to read browser history

Tags: swift, safari, browser-history, safari-extension

Can the new Safari App Extensions read browser history? If so, what are the API calls?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions)

Comment: @Scriptable I know you're trying to make a point, but it's not a valid one. My question is fine for StackOverflow; asking for directions on how to implement a specific action using code. *All* questions at StackOverflow could be answered by some documentation - the reason people use SO is that they don't know where to search specifically.

Comment: I don't believe that your question is on-topic for StackOverflow... It asks two questions, is very broad, shows no research/attempt. But that is just my opinion.. I'll leave it to the rest of the community to decide

Comment: It's one question and it's super precise. Only two possbile answers could be given: 1. No, and here's a reference to prove it's not possible. Or 2. Yes, and here's a reference to the API call to read Safari's browser history.

Comment: It's getting downvoted, yet even with a bounty there is still no answer... seems like it's not a easy question to answer afterall...

Comment: I looked into this a little this morning and I don't think it is possible, you only have access to the current page content

Comment: @Scriptable Thanks for looking into it. Kinda weird Apple doesn't offer such basic functionality... Chrome offers much more, with clear documentation (https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/history).

Comment: yeah, it's Apple and privacy, they restrict us alot. :(

Comment: A year later, and I still feel annoyed that this is getting downvotes. The question is purposefully succinct and to the point. It is clear what is being asked and it's a relevant problem (note that no one was able to answer it so far). This should be the hallmark of a _good_ question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching, I could not find any mentions of a history API (such as in the case of Chrome, see https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/history). So the absence of evidence in this case is evidence of absence.